# Selenium Equivalent in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, selenium

I have used Selenium for making python projects and now I want to try similar projects in Swift with Xcode using Selenium. Unfortunately, I quickly found out Selenium is not for Swift or iOS apps.

I have been spending the last two days researching on a Selenium alternatives for mobile but have not been able to find anything. Everything I have found so far seems to be outdated. Is there any alternative that is for the current version of Swift and Xcode?

Comment: Is Appium outdated? It worked well when I used it if you're looking for selenium for mobile.

Comment: I saw Appium as an option but all the docs seemed old. Also there's not much on attaching it and using it in Xcode iOS app. Unlike CocoaPods where it's just using the PodFile to install libraries.

Comment: Hi @fphelp. I have just same issue as you. Did you solve your problem? If so, could you advance me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ONLY option available for automating iOS devices is with Appium and the XCUITest driver.

(Unless there are other drivers recently made that utilize XCUITest, which is an apple tool set).

[XCUITest-driver can be found here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver)

Luckily, many of the driver commands will be the same as, say, the UIAutomator2 driver for android. They inherit the same base classes/interfaces after all.

You will need to run these tests on your Mac laptop or desktop, as it is not possible to interact with an iOS device as a developer on non apple products.

Here is a set of server bash and python scripts that I used to launch a video game on to iOS (and android devices). This is not identical to what you need, but it should provide a lot of help that you might need.

[Github server files (python and bash)](https://github.com/disruptorbeam/trilleon/tree/master/server)

[Wiki explaining how to implement and get this working](https://github.com/disruptorbeam/trilleon/wiki/Setup-Linux-Mac)

Comment: Sounds good and I will start trying it out. If I were to use Appium and XCUITest driver would the app be able to work without being connected to my computer? I mean in the sense where I can publish the app on the app store and it can still utilize Appium with no problems?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is possible to connect from the build device wirelessly via wifi with an iOS device. However, it is A LOT of extra work to get that to work right and reliably. Any wifi interruption for a split second can cause the socket to err and the test run to stall. I would recommend wired connections, at least to start, since this is your first time setting it up. Get it working wired, and then take the next step to wireless.

Comment: Ok great I will see what I can do!

Comment: I recomend Cucumber for Unit and automation tests

Comment: Just fyi, but Cucumber is not a driver, which is what this was about. Cucumber is a framework for writing tests in Gherkin syntax, whereas they want to know if there are other drivers that will run tests. But you can certainly use Appium with Cucumber.